# Use chrome to send HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, google-chrome, web-scraping, httpwebrequest

My code for web scraping is

```
public static string getSourceCode(string url)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                req.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36";
                //req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0";
                HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
                string sourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
                res.Close();
                return sourceCode;
            }catch(Exception ae){
            return string.Empty;
            }

        }
```

I want to send this request using chrome only as source code is differing depending upon browser.

Any solutions?

Comment: What exactly is different about the source code from chrome versus other browsers? The only way that I can see a web server changing the source code based on the browser that is sending the request would be via the user agent which you are already using. It is entirely possible that chrome does something internally that is formatting the source code differently than other browsers.

Comment: Without knowing more about your particular situation, the only thing I can really suggest is to use a web debugging proxy tool such as [Telerik Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to view the headers that chrome sends to the url in question and then do your best to emulate the headers in your code. If this doesn't help then chrome is obviously changing the code internally. Depending on what differences you are noticing you will most likely have to manipulate the source code manually after you get your response from the server to match what it is you need the source to look like.

Comment: @JoeyJoeJoeJrShabadoo sorry for the late reply and thnx for ur reply, Actually there are sections on my website so depending on that section html data changes, with url in browser same. I have just given chrome as my option to use when this section change on chrome html i am receiving also changes.